# Find number coprime to modulus

Tags: java, math, rsa, arithmetic-expressions, modular-arithmetic

I've been doing some research on the RSA encryption system, it's pretty simple to code one using small primes, as there aren't too many possibilities and performance is not a real issue.

Here's how RSA Works:

- First, you generate a `n` value, product from 2 primes picked up randomly:

  ```
  n = p * q
  ```

  - Then you need your public key, called **e**. It can be any number coprime to φ(n):

    mcd(φ(n), e) = 1
  - According to the **Euler function**, `φ(n) = (p-1)(q-1)`
  - You still need your private key, known as `d`, which is the inverse of `e on modulo **φ(n)`.
  - So `d * e = 1 (mod φ(n))`
  - `n` and `e` are your public values, when `d` is your private key. Nobody should know `p` or `q`, as with those values it would be possible to get `φ(n)`, and use it to calculate `d`.
- To encrypt a message, we use `M = m^e (mod n)`, where `m` is the original message, and `M` is the encrypted one. So, everybody can send you an encrypted message you can read, by using your public values.
- To decrypt a message, you use `d`, as it's the inverse of `e`, so `M^d = (m^e)^d = m (mod n)`. The message can be decrypted, but only using `d`.

Knowing this, to encrypt a message we just need to get two random primes, calculate `n, e, d,` and make our encryption and decryption methods.

---

This seems pretty easy in theory, now let's turn this into java code:

I first choose two random primes, the bigger the number, the stronger the encryption. So I'll choose `p = 1644623` and `q = 1644751`. According to [this page](http://compoasso.free.fr/primelistweb/page/prime/liste_online_en.php), they are primes.

```
BigInteger p = new BigInteger("1644623");
BigInteger q = new BigInteger("1644751");
```

Then, on my init method, I initialize `n, e` and `d:`

```
BigInteger p = new BigInteger("1644623");
BigInteger q = new BigInteger("1644751");

BigInteger n;
BigInteger e;
BigInteger d;

void init() {
    n = p.multiply(q);

    BigInteger pn = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));

    e = n.subtract(pn);
    while (!mcd(pn, e).equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        e = e.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    d = e.modPow(new BigInteger("-1"), pn);
}
```

I used BigInteger instead of long, as the values used are extremely big.

In theory, everything works. Practically, `pn = 2704992034500`, so checking if `mcd(pn, e) = 1`, and if not adding 1 to `e` and trying again it's not an option. This program is running since 30 minutes, at an average of 150.000 numbers / second. `e = 548151505` and still not found `mcd(pn, e) = 1`.

---

Is there any way to find `e` in a reasonable time?

---

Comment: Isn't that what the Extended Euclidean Algorithm does? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: There is no such thing as `mcd`. Perhaps you made a typo, because it's the `gcd` or Euclidean Algorithm.

Comment: That's for getting the private key (d) from the public one (e), which is the next step and can be done just by d (mod n) = e^-1. What I'm trying to do is to generate e, the public key.

Comment: @ArtjomB it's the absolutely same, only that in my country it's known as mcd (maximo comun divisor), which is the spanish translation of gcd (greatest common divisor).

Comment: As user448810 answered, you don't need to find *e*, you just set it to some common value. If you're really interested in finding a "unique" *e*, then this question is probably better suited for [math.se] or [crypto.se]. Please check if there is already a similar question asked. There is a reason why Fermat Primes are chosen as *e* and that is the number of set bits must be low for fast encryption and fast signature verification.

Comment: @Thilo No, it isn't.

Comment: @Juanco: Can you show us the implementation of `mcd`?

Answer (score 2):

Any prime number will be co-prime to the modulus, by definition, so you don't need to search for one, just pick a prime number. Since the encryption key is public, most RSA implementations use something that makes it easy to compute the modular exponentiation: 3 and 65537 = 2 ** 16 + 1 are both prime, and both are commonly used for the encryption key.

Comment: Common choices are [Fermat numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number). Also, 3 is a very bad choice if textbook RSA is used.

Comment: @ArtjomB.: But in that case, using 3 isn't the problem. The problem is textbook RSA.

Comment: "Any prime number will be co-prime to the modulus, by definition". This isn't true: a small prime number could easily be a divisor of `phi(n)`. In the example that the OP gave, `phi(n)` is divisible by 3, so using `e = 3` isn't an option, for example. If you're going to always use `3`, you then need to make some extra effort to make sure that neither of your chosen primes is congruent to 1 modulo `3`. Similarly if you decide in advance that you want to use `e = 65537`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: In other words, what's important for the exponents is co-primality to `phi(n)`, *not* co-primality to `n`.

Comment: @JamesKPolk: Ah, good point; my too-quick reading failed to notice the "co-prime to *the modulus*" bit. So I take it back: the statement I quoted *is* true (assuming you don't pick p or q itself), but not terribly helpful.